# Change Properties of the Hamburger Button in Xamarin WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin, hamburger-menu, keyboard-navigation

I need to set the Hamburger Button to Focusable and TabStop, any idea?

Comment: Hi, could you share an image or sample code to explain the expected effect? I will check that in local site.

Comment: Hi, I want to select the hamburger button via Tab Navigation. The problem is that the button is autogenerated as part of a MasterDetailPage. I would need to set the button IsTabStop and Focusable to true, to have the desired effect.

Comment: Okey, if so, it seems need to create a custom tabbed page, then can have a hamburger button be modifed.